# Как удалить встроенный в тему модуль Visual Composer и установить вместо него плагин?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Есть сайт на `wordpress` в теме которого встроен модуль конструктора **WPBakery Visual Composer**. Проблема в том, что на обновленном движке некоторые элементы конструктора отрабатывают косячно (т.к. сам моду устарел).. Вопрос: как открепить встроенный модуль конструктора в тему и установить **Visual Composer** уже плагином, чтобы компоненты модуля не конфликтовали с ним?
вот такой код вызова конструктора в `functions.php` темы:

```
if (!class_exists('WPBakeryVisualComposerAbstract')) {
  $dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/wpbakery/';
  $composer_settings = Array(
      'APP_ROOT'      => $dir . '/js_composer',
      'WP_ROOT'       => dirname( dirname( dirname( dirname($dir ) ) ) ). '/',
      'APP_DIR'       => basename( $dir ) . '/js_composer/',
      'CONFIG'        => $dir . '/js_composer/config/',
      'ASSETS_DIR'    => 'assets/',
      'COMPOSER'      => $dir . '/js_composer/composer/',
      'COMPOSER_LIB'  => $dir . '/js_composer/composer/lib/',
      'SHORTCODES_LIB'  => $dir . '/js_composer/composer/lib/shortcodes/',
      'USER_DIR_NAME'  => 'extendvc/vc_templates', /* Path relative to your current theme, where VC should look for new shortcode templates */

      //for which content types Visual Composer should be enabled by default
      'default_post_types' => Array('page','post','portfolio_page')
  );
  require_once locate_template('/wpbakery/js_composer/js_composer.php');
  $wpVC_setup->init($composer_settings);
}

// Initialising Shortcodes
if (class_exists('WPBakeryVisualComposerAbstract')) {
  require_once locate_template('/extendvc/extend-vc.php');
}
```

Если его комментирую и устанавливаю плагин **Visual Composer**, то получаю следующую ошибку:

```
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wpb_getImageBySize() (previously declared in /home/likemedi/public_html/wp-content/themes/subway/wpbakery‌​/js_composer/compose‌​r/lib/helpers.php:15‌​) in /home/likemedi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/in‌​clude/helpers/helper‌​s.php on line 114`
```

Answer (score 1):

Полностью комментируйте блок подключения композера в тему внутри functions.php и ставьте его отдельным плагином через админку WordPress.

Comment: вопрос в том, чтобы сохранить и перенести блоки а плагин композера?

Comment: Если были блоки в теме, я бы их перенес в свой плагин (`js_composer_extended`, например). Тем более, что блок создаются в простом варианте через функцию `vc_map` внутр хука `vc_init`.

Comment: получаю `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wpb_getImageBySize() (previously declared in /home/likemedi/public_html/wp-content/themes/subway/wpbakery/js_composer/composer/lib/helpers.php:15) in /home/likemedi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/helpers/helpers.php on line 114`